# overwrite the css property

Tags: html, css

I have 2 parent div view 1 and 2. and want to hide the second view but display decription of 2nd view.

desired output is: 
   **title

   sample description1

   sample description2**

```css
.view2{
  display:none;
}
.view2 .desc{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="view1">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description1</div>
</div>
<div class="view2">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:not()` selector.

Try this

```css
.view2 *:not(.desc) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="view1">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description1</div>
</div>
<div class="view2">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update Css**

```
.view2 .title{
  display:none;
}
```

**Snippet Example Below**

```css
.view2 .title{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="view1">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description1</div>
</div>
<div class="view2">
  <div class="title">
  <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desc"> sample description2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the privelage to comment but you can use java script for that poupose.

```
element.style.visibility = "hidden";
```